# Communication Error in webservices

Tags: web-services

Hai Friends

I am using webservice for validating the Email in the Online Its is Working fine in only one system where there is no restricts for some websites.In our office in some system  i cant access any websites regarding the "Email".if the word email comes it says "it is a restricted site".if run that Application in some system it says Communication error- "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine" .how to over come this error by coding and run the applicationfot time being  any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me as if your intranet's gate to the wild wild west (www) is protected by a service that filters traffic based on a keyword list, where 'email' is one of the keywords.

If that is the case, then you have to talk with the admins of this filter service to adjust the filter rules.

Comment: if i filter the word means it seems to create a big problem  for particular application.then all will check mails.how to prevent via coding for that particular application.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your are going through a proxy, so depending on your corporate policy you could either bypass the proxy OR have your system admins set your web application servers as a trusted source.